# Глобальные переменные JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть два активити в первом в переменную закладывается значение. Во втором активити это значение необходимо получить. Как передать переменную из одного активити в другое я знаю. Но как сделать глобальную переменную которая будет видна всем активити без передачи и если запускается первое активити оно переназначает эту переменную а во втором активити можно напрямую обратиться к этой переменной.

Как такое реализовать ?

Comment: Можно в перовой активити записывать значение переменной в SharedPreferences. А во второй его считывать.

Answer (score 1):

Создавать глобальные переменные - это плохая практика, используйте как написали передачу и возврат из второй активити значения. Если использовать глобальные переменные бывают часто трудно уловимые баги, потратьте время и сделайте нормально и потом не переделывать по десять раз.